# Execute Multiple Raw SQL Statements in Loopback 4 Using execute()

Tags: node.js, orm, loopback, loopback4

Loopback 4 uses its own Juggler ORM. But I can't seem to find the required parameter to pass to be able to execute multiple SQL statements using the "execute" method.

```
await this.myRepository.execute(`SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = 1; SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = 1;`);
```

This should be possible using any other ORM by setting a "multi-statement" option to true.

Comment: Right now, its not possible in juggler.

Answer (score 1):

I think only way to achieve this is by doing promise all.

Try this

```
await Promise.all([
    this.myRepository.execute(`SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = 1`),
    this.myRepository.execute(`SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = 1`)
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are trying to execute a "SELECT" statement you would want to catch/return the result output. I am not sure how the multiple results will get handled, so, I think you will need to execute single statement like below:

```
const Result = await this.myRepository.execute(
  `SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = 1`
);
```

However, the way to pass parameters in execute method is by using second parameter as an array:

```
await this.myRepository.execute(
  `SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = ?; 
   SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = ?;`,
  [FirstTableId,SecondTableId]
);
```